# Is there a way of enforcing the correct schema based on a property in OpenAPI v3?

Tags: rest, openapi

Given the following OpenAPI V3 schema:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Animals API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /v1/animals:
    post:
      requestBody:
        description: Animal
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                animal: 
                  type: string
                  enum: 
                    - cat
                    - dog
                payload:
                  oneOf:
                    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/DogSchema'
                    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/CatSchema'
      responses:
        201:
          description: Created
        400:
          description: Bad request
components:
  schemas:
    DogSchema:
      type: object
      properties:
        dogProperty1:
          type: string
        dogProperty2:
          type: integer

    CatSchema:
      type: object
      properties:
        catProperty1:
          type: string
        catProperty2:
          type: boolean
```

Is it possible to specify that if the `animal` property is `dog` the DogSchema must apply to the `payload` and that when `animal` is `cat` the CatSchema must apply so that the e.g. the `requestBody`

```
{
  "animal": "cat",
  "payload": {
    "dogProperty1": "some value",
    "dogProperty2": 0
  }
}
```

will result in a response indicating invalid request e.g. status code 422?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `oneOf` to define both instances.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Animals API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /v1/animals:
    post:
      requestBody:
        description: Animal
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              oneOf:
                - type: object
                  title: CatSchema
                  required:
                    - animal
                  properties:
                    animal:
                      type: string
                      enum:
                        - cat
                    payload:
                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/CatSchema'
                - type: object
                  title: DogSchema
                  required:
                    - animal
                  properties:
                    animal:
                      type: string
                      enum:
                        - dog
                    payload:
                      $ref: '#/components/schemas/DogSchema'
      responses:
        201:
          description: Created
        400:
          description: Bad request
components:
  schemas:
    DogSchema:
      type: object
      properties:
        dogProperty1:
          type: string
        dogProperty2:
          type: integer

    CatSchema:
      type: object
      properties:
        catProperty1:
          type: string
        catProperty2:
          type: boolean
```